# Pass state to another components function with props

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a simple weather api with Google Maps api and I'm almost finished. However, when I was creating the Google Maps, I need to pass in the Lat and Long props to my child components function. I managed to successfully pass the state to the child component. However, in my child component I have another function that contains my google code. When I try to plug in it's lat,lng coordinates into the API, it returns 0,0 reason being is I don't have access to props within this child components function. However, I have access to the props within the return and render.

So my question is how would I have access to the props within the child components function from my parent component?

**Parent Component**

Here is my code:

```js
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Weathermodule from './weatherModule';

class Weather extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            city: '',
            state: '',
            country: '',
            weatherCity: '',
            weatherState: '',
            weatherLongitude: '',
            weatherLatitude: '',
            weatherDays: [],
            weatherDate: [],
            weatherIcons: [],
            weatherAlt: [],
            weatherTemp: [],
            weatherpresentTemp: [],
            errors: '',
            showweatherComponent: false,
        }
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    async onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const APIkey = 'hiddenfortest';
        const city = this.state.city;
        const state = this.state.state;
        const country = this.state.country;

        if(this.state.city === '' || this.state.state === '') {
            this.setState({errors: 'Please fill out all required fields.'})
        } else {
            this.setState({
                showweatherComponent: true,
            });
            const res = await fetch(`http://api.wunderground.com/api/${APIkey}/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/${country}/${state}/${city}.json`);
            const json = await res.json();

            // For logging response
            // console.log(json);

            this.setState({
                weatherCity: json.location.city,
                weatherState: json.location.state,
                weatherLatitude: json.location.lat,
                weatherLongitude: json.location.lon,
                weatherZip: json.location.zip,
                // Weather Days ex. Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday etc..
                weatherDays: [
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].date.weekday,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].date.weekday,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].date.weekday,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].date.weekday,
                ],
                // Weather Dates
                weatherDate: [
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].date.month,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].date.day,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].date.month,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].date.day,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].date.month,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].date.day,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].date.month,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].date.day,
                ],
                // Weather Icons generated for the weather dates
                weatherIcons: [
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].icon_url,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].icon_url,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].icon_url,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].icon_url,
                ],
                // Weather Alt Attributes appended to the jsx img tag
                weatherAlt: [
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].icon,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].icon,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].icon,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].icon,
                ],
                // High/Low Fahrenheit temperature for the weather dates
                weatherpresentTemp: [
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].low.fahrenheit,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].high.fahrenheit,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].low.fahrenheit,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].high.fahrenheit,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].low.fahrenheit,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].high.fahrenheit,
                    json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].low.fahrenheit,
                ],
                // Today temperature fahrenheit, and celsius
                weatherTemp: [
                    json.current_observation.temp_f,
                    json.current_observation.temp_c,
                ]
            })
            // console.log(this.state);
        }
    }

    render(){
        const latitude = parseFloat(this.state.weatherLatitude).toFixed(2) === NaN ? '' : parseFloat(this.state.weatherLatitude).toFixed(2)
        const longitude = parseFloat(this.state.weatherLongitude).toFixed(2) === NaN ? '' : parseFloat(this.state.weatherLongitude).toFixed(2)
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Weather Demo</h1>
                {this.state.errors !== '' ? <p style={{color:'#E2231A'}}>Please fill out all required fields</p> : ''}
                <form
                    method="POST"
                    onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)}
                >
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="city"
                        placeholder="City"
                        onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.city}
                    />
                    <label>State</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="state"
                        placeholder="State"
                        onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.state}
                    />
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name="country"
                        placeholder="Country"
                        onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.country}
                    />
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-regular"
                        onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}
                    >
                    Get Weather
                    </button>
                </form>
                {/* Don't show component until submit button clicked, once clicked, pass state down to props for other component */}
                {
                    this.state.showweatherComponent ?
                    <Weathermodule
                        city={this.state.city}
                        state={this.state.state}
                        country={this.state.country}
                        weatherCity={this.state.weatherCity}
                        weatherState={this.state.weatherState}
                        weatherLongitude={this.state.weatherLongitude}
                        weatherLatitude={this.state.weatherLatitude}
                        weatherDays={this.state.weatherDays}
                        weatherDate={this.state.weatherDate}
                        weatherIcons={this.state.weatherIcons}
                        weatherAlt={this.state.weatherAlt}
                        weatherTemp={this.state.weatherTemp}
                        weatherpresentTemp={this.state.weatherpresentTemp}
                        longitude={longitude}
                        latitude={latitude}
                />
                    :
                    null
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Weather;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**Child Component**

```js
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Weathermodule extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        var locations = {
            lat: Number(this.props.weatherLatitude),
            lng: Number(this.props.weatherLongitude)
        };
        console.log(locations);
        let map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: locations,
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        });
        console.log(this.props);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Weather</h1>
                <div className="row" id="weather-description">
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <h2>{this.props.weatherCity}, {this.props.weatherState}</h2>
                        <img src={this.props.weatherIcons[0]} alt={this.props.weatherAlt[0]} />
                        <h3>{this.props.weatherTemp[0]}<sup>o</sup>F</h3>
                        <h4>({this.props.weatherTemp[1]}<sup>o</sup>C)</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">
                        <p>Latitude: {this.props.latitude}, Longitude: {this.props.longitude}</p>

                        <div id="map" className="map-alignment"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3" id="red">
                        <h3>{this.props.weatherDays[0]}</h3>
                        <p>{this.props.weatherDate[0] + "/" + this.props.weatherDate[1]}</p>
                        <img src={this.props.weatherIcons[0]} alt={this.props.weatherAlt[0]} />
                        <p>{this.props.weatherpresentTemp[0]}<sup>o</sup> | {this.props.weatherpresentTemp[1]}<sup>o</sup>F</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3" id="blue">
                        <h3>{this.props.weatherDays[1]}</h3>
                        <p>{this.props.weatherDate[2] + "/" + this.props.weatherDate[3]}</p>
                        <img src={this.props.weatherIcons[1]} alt={this.props.weatherAlt[1]} />
                        <p>{this.props.weatherpresentTemp[2]}<sup>o</sup> | {this.props.weatherpresentTemp[3]}<sup>o</sup>F</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3" id="black">
                        <h3>{this.props.weatherDays[2]}</h3>
                        <p>{this.props.weatherDate[4] + "/" + this.props.weatherDate[5]}</p>
                        <img src={this.props.weatherIcons[2]} alt={this.props.weatherAlt[2]} />
                        <p>{this.props.weatherpresentTemp[4]}<sup>o</sup> | {this.props.weatherpresentTemp[5]}<sup>o</sup>F</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-3" id="green">
                        <h3>{this.props.weatherDays[3]}</h3>
                        <p>{this.props.weatherDate[6] + "/" + this.props.weatherDate[7]}</p>
                        <img src={this.props.weatherIcons[3]} alt={this.props.weatherAlt[3]} />
                        <p>{this.props.weatherpresentTemp[6]}<sup>o</sup> | {this.props.weatherpresentTemp[7]}<sup>o</sup>F</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Weathermodule;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onSubmit()` function in your `Weather` component, you call `this.setState({showweatherComponent: true,});` then you call an asynchronous function to get all your map data.

When you call `setState` the first time, you `render()` function conditional will then render your `Weathermodule` component, with the current value of state, which at this point in time would be default values since your asynchronous API call hasn't yet returned data and you haven't yet setState with the new data.

By the time your api call has returned data and you have set state, your `Weathermodule` component has long since mounted. You aren't checking for `componentWillReceiveProps` on the child to see if you should update your map.

You are trying not to use state in your `Weathermodule` but it would be easier to manage if you did. Add a function to set up your map, rather than having your map functionality directly in `compenentDidMount`. This way, you can call your map function from multiple places in your lifecycle as necessary.

Think through which way you want to solve. You can either change the placement of your first `setState()` call in `onSubmit()` or add more lifecycle events to your child component, or both.

**In the Parent**

```
async onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const APIkey = 'hiddenfortest';
    const city = this.state.city;
    const state = this.state.state;
    const country = this.state.country;

    if(this.state.city === '' || this.state.state === '') {
        this.setState({errors: 'Please fill out all required fields.'})
    } else {
        // no need to start rendering your map until you have data
        const res = await fetch(`http://api.wunderground.com/api/${APIkey}/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/${country}/${state}/${city}.json`);
        const json = await res.json();

        // For logging response
        // console.log(json);

        this.setState({
            weatherCity: json.location.city,
            weatherState: json.location.state,
            weatherLatitude: json.location.lat,
            weatherLongitude: json.location.lon,
            weatherZip: json.location.zip,
            // Weather Days ex. Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday etc..
            weatherDays: [
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].date.weekday,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].date.weekday,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].date.weekday,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].date.weekday,
            ],
            // Weather Dates
            weatherDate: [
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].date.month,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].date.day,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].date.month,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].date.day,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].date.month,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].date.day,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].date.month,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].date.day,
            ],
            // Weather Icons generated for the weather dates
            weatherIcons: [
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].icon_url,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].icon_url,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].icon_url,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].icon_url,
            ],
            // Weather Alt Attributes appended to the jsx img tag
            weatherAlt: [
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].icon,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].icon,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].icon,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].icon,
            ],
            // High/Low Fahrenheit temperature for the weather dates
            weatherpresentTemp: [
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].low.fahrenheit,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].high.fahrenheit,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[1].low.fahrenheit,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].high.fahrenheit,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[2].low.fahrenheit,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].high.fahrenheit,
                json.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[3].low.fahrenheit,
            ],
            // Today temperature fahrenheit, and celsius
            weatherTemp: [
                json.current_observation.temp_f,
                json.current_observation.temp_c,
            ],
            //now you have data, show your component
            showweatherComponent: true
        })
```

**In the Child**

```
componentDidMount(){
    var locations = {
        lat: Number(this.props.weatherLatitude),
        lng: Number(this.props.weatherLongitude)
    };
    this.renderMap(locations);
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

    //ideally this is why giving this component state is important
    //you only would call renderMap if you received new lat/lon coords
    //that is, you would compare state with nextProps

    var locations = {
        lat: Number(nextProps.weatherLatitude),
        lng: Number(nextProps.weatherLongitude)
    };
    this.renderMap(locations);
}
renderMap = locations => {
    let map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: locations,
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    });
}
```